# How to change SlidingDrawer handle click sound?

Tags: android

I implemented a `SlidingDrawer` in my `Activity` and everything works fine so far.
Now I want to proceed custom sound by clicking the handle. But, it doesn't seem to possible to override anything the handle.

Is it possible to proceed custom click sound?

Comment: Why don't you get code of the class : [Source][https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.java]  and change the soundeffect in onTouch.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just changed playSoundEffect() to my own sound.

Comment: If you wish, you can write answer to your own question with little bit of knowledge of changes you did in the class and how for future references.

Comment: I wrote an answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED :**

1. Copy [SlidingDrawer](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.java) class to your Application and change class name to `MSlidingDrawer`.
2. Open layout xml file and change widget `SlidingDrawer` to your own `MSlidingDrawer`.
3. Open `MSlidingDrawer` class.
4. find `playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);` and change to your own method for play sound.

Comment: Great.! Keep exploring and keep sharing.